# Using condition have to pass Mainactivity to register class or signup to register class

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-xml

i have three class Mainactivity,signup,register;here i would like to pass Mainactivity to register class or signup to register class.my codes given below!then i like to validate (USERNAME with Maximum & Minimum Character;Mobile Only 10 digit with country code and number start with 9,8,7;Password and confrom password matcher;Email id validation etc).

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText main_edt_Mobile;
    final EditText main_edt_Password;

    final Button main_btn_Signup;
    final Button main_btn_Login;

    final String main_mobile;
    final String main_password;

    main_edt_Mobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_mobile);
    main_edt_Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_password);

    main_btn_Login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
    main_btn_Signup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_signup);

    main_btn_Login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "LOGED IN", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Register.class );

            String main_mobile = main_edt_Mobile.getText().toString();
            int conversion_Integer =Integer.parseInt(main_mobile);
            String main_password = main_edt_Password.getText().toString();

            i.putExtra("key_main_m",main_mobile);
            i.putExtra("key_main_p",main_password);

            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
    main_btn_Signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "SIGNED UP", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Signup.class );
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}}
```

public class Signup extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.signup);

    final String firstName;
    final String lastName;
    final String mobile ;
    final String password;
    final String email;

    final EditText edt_Signup_FirstName;
    final EditText edt_Signup_LastName;
    final EditText edt_Signup_Mobile;
    final EditText edt_Signup_Password;
    final EditText edt_Signup_Email;

    Button btn_Signup_Register;

    edt_Signup_FirstName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_signup_first_name);
    edt_Signup_LastName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_signup_last_name);
    edt_Signup_Mobile=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_signup_mobile);
    edt_Signup_Password=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_signup_password);
    edt_Signup_Email=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_signup_email);

    btn_Signup_Register=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_signup_register);

    btn_Signup_Register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent i =new Intent(Signup.this,Register.class);

            String firstName = edt_Signup_FirstName.getText().toString();
            String lastName = edt_Signup_LastName.getText().toString();
            String mobile = edt_Signup_Mobile.getText().toString();
            int conversion_Integer =Integer.parseInt(mobile);
            String password = edt_Signup_Password.getText().toString();
            String email = edt_Signup_Email.getText().toString();

            i.putExtra("key_f",firstName);
            i.putExtra("key_l",lastName);
            i.putExtra("key_m",mobile);
            i.putExtra("key_p",password);
            i.putExtra("key_e",email);

            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
}}

public class Register extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register);

    TextView txt_FirstName,txt_LastName,txt_Mobile,txt_Password,txt_Email;

    txt_Email =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_email);
    txt_FirstName =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_firstName);
    txt_LastName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_lastName);
    txt_Mobile = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_mobile);
    txt_Password = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_password);

    Intent i = getIntent();

    String firstname = i.getStringExtra("key_f");
    String lastname = i.getStringExtra("key_l");
    String mobile = i.getStringExtra("key_m");
    String password = i.getStringExtra("key_p");
    String email = i.getStringExtra("key_e");

    txt_Email.setText("EMAIL : " +email);
    txt_FirstName.setText("FIRSTNAME : " +firstname);
    txt_LastName.setText("LASTNAME : " +lastname);
    txt_Mobile.setText("MOBILE : " +mobile);
    txt_Password.setText("PASSWORD : " +password);
}}
```